# Dropbox offline on USB

Tags: sync, usb-flash-drive, dropbox, offline-files

I have a Dropbox account and I use it to share files among a few PCs.

Now I need to use these files on a PC where Dropbox is blocked. I'm thinking on moving these files to a USB and use them there. The issue is how to synch them later.

I suppose that Dropbox's Windows client works fine offline, and when Internet is detected it should automatically sync. If I can config it to put its files on pendrive, would it detect when pendrive is plugged in and automatically sync? If so, I could do that at home, sync, unmount pendrive, use it offline, and when come back I'd just mount it back and client sync its outdated files.

The issue for that is all my PCs already have Dropbox installed. Is it able to put same account on multiple folders on the same Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep your Dropbox running on all your PCs. Use sync software such as rsync to sync from Dropbox to pendrive. Use your pendrive elsewhere. When you return, you perform a sync from the pendrive to Dropbox.